# How to configurate Log4j to avoid consecutive logs with same content?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

**Is that possible without having to code an adapter?**

```
log.info("test1"); //12/07/2012 10:08:51
log.info("test1"); //12/07/2012 10:08:52
log.info("test2"); //12/07/2012 10:08:53
log.info("test2"); //12/07/2012 10:08:54
log.info("test3"); //12/07/2012 10:08:55
log.info("test1"); //12/07/2012 10:08:56
```

Expected output:

> 12/07/2012 10:08:51 INFO - teste1
>   12/07/2012 10:08:53 INFO - teste2
>   12/07/2012 10:08:55 INFO - teste3
>   12/07/2012 10:08:56 INFO - teste1

Comment: pretty sure the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

A [filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html) should work.

(spacing because stackoverflow wants it)

Comment: That's not how I understood the question.

Comment: the question says "without having to code".  using a custom filter would involve writing custom code.

Comment: obviously, it's up to the OP what he really meant, but considering that there is no "Adapater" class in log4j, i took that to mean "code something which adapts the behavior of log4j to what i want" (aka a custom Filter).